How to copy and paste data into n new workbooks based on two filters with VBA?
My goal is to copy and paste data from 1 Master workbook into n separate workbooks.
The user should be able to select a "Desk" in the Master which then triggers the creation of X amount of workbooks for each person in this Desk
(each recipient is not not allowed to see the data of others, that's why the data per Desk must be split).
The filter should work on two criterias:

The 1st criteria is the "Desk". There are 3 options (Desk 1, Desk 2, Desk 3)
The 2nd criteria is the people assigned to each desk. I hava a mapping table for person per desk in one of the Master sheets

So far I was only able to create a workbook which shows the Desk data, but I need to split this data further for each Person:
Option Explicit

 Sub copy_data()

    Dim count_col As Long
    Dim count_row As Long
    Dim RelationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim AccountSheet As Worksheet
    Dim InstructionSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet
    Dim desk As String
    Dim START_CELL As String

    Set InstructionSheet = Sheet2
    Set RelationSheet = Sheet1
    Set AccountSheet = Sheet3
    desk = InstructionSheet.Cells(14, 3).Text
    START_CELL = "B5"

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    sht.Name = "RELATION LEVEL"

    With RelationSheet.Range(START_CELL)
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=desk
        .CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With

    sht.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    sht.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    With ActiveWindow
        If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
        .SplitColumn = 1
        .SplitRow = 2
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    RelationSheet.ShowAllData
    RelationSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

   
End Sub


I don't know how to add the second filter to the code to create further workbooks for each person.
In the example below, selecting "Desk 1" and then running the macro (via button) should create 2 separate workbooks; one for Anastasia and one for Rob. The name of each report should combine the desk and person name, e.g. "Desk_1_Anastasia".
If there isn't a desk+person combination, an empty report shall be generated (= copy table header to the report).
Mapping table:



Desk
Person




Desk 1
Anastasia


Desk 1
Rob


Desk 2
Tom


Desk 3
Michael


Desk 3
Sophia



I prepared an Excel with dummy data to illustrate the source data better:
Excel with example data

It would be beneficial to address one question in each post. After resolving the current issue, feel free to create a new post for any additional questions.

Got it. I removed the other parts to leave this post strictly about filtering for the desk and then creating for each person in this desk a separate report.

What is mapping table for?

To know in which Desk each person belongs to. My idea was to use it as sort of lookup, so that the code knows "Desk 1 -> Anastasia and Rob need the report"

Desk 1 -> Anastasia and Rob Is it a report or two reports? If there isn't desk+person conbination row in Tables, do you want to skip the combination or just copy table header to the report? What's the file name of report? Please provide detail about your question.

Edited the post to add the missing information. Desk 1 -> Anastasia and Rob should be two separate reports. Both reports should be created when selecting Desk 1 and then running the macro (via button).  If a combination is not available, it should just copy the table header to the report. The reports should all be "Desk_X_Person Name", e.g. "Desk_1_Anastasia".


Source data is formatted as a table (Insert > Table) in your file. Utilizing ListObject makes it easier to manage.

Microsoft documentation:

ListObject object (Excel)

Option Explicit
Sub copy_data()
    Dim RelationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim AccountSheet As Worksheet
    Dim InstructionSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook, sht, desk As String
    Dim rngLookUp As Range, i As Long, sDesk As String, sPerson As String
    Dim arrData, sFile As String, sPath As String
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Set InstructionSheet = Sheet2
    Set RelationSheet = Sheet1
    Set AccountSheet = Sheet3
    desk = InstructionSheet.Cells(14, 3).Text
    If Len(desk) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    ' load lookup table into an array
    With InstructionSheet.Range("M1").CurrentRegion
        arrData = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Value
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' loop through lookup table
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sDesk = arrData(i, 1)
        If sDesk = desk Then ' match desk
            sPerson = arrData(i, 2)
            ' report workbook name
            sFile = Replace(sDesk, " ", "_") & "_" & sPerson & ".xlsx"
            Set wb = Workbooks.Add
            Set sht = ActiveSheet
            sht.Name = RelationSheet.Name
            With RelationSheet.ListObjects(1)
                If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
                    .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
                End If
                ' filter desk and person
                .Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=sDesk
                .Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sPerson
                ' copy filtered table
                .Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy sht.Range("A1")
                .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            End With
            ' add a new sheet for AccountLevel
            Set sht = wb.Sheets.Add
            sht.Name = AccountSheet.Name
            With AccountSheet.ListObjects(1)
                If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
                    .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
                End If
                .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sDesk
                .Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sPerson
                .Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy sht.Range("A1")
                .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            End With
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ' save report, overwrite if exists
            wb.SaveAs sPath & sFile
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            wb.Close
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub


Thanks so much, this works perfectly in the example file.
But the code did not work in the real file and after some testing I realized that it's because my "table" in the RELATION LEVEL is a Pivot Table. In ACCOUNT LEVEL it's a normal table.
With a pivot table this code always leads to an error ("Autofilter method of Range class failed").  Very sorry, I didn't know that there is a difference for copying from Pivots.
I will update my question. Is there an easy way to adjust it please?

What should I do when someone answers my question?
What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?

Thank you, I reverted the post back so that others can use the above solution. Will post a follow-up!
